# Use pug (jade) to selectively generate table of contents for articles in specified folders

Tags: pug, block, extend, partial, harp

I am using harp version 0.21.0 with jade support to develop a static site on Windows 7. The harp documentation links below show examples for using _layout.ejs for Nested Layouts and how to create a list of blog posts:

https://harpjs.com/docs/development/layout

https://harpjs.com/recipes/blog-posts-list

I would like to put links to articles in the side container only when the current page is in a group folder that contains more than one article as shown below.

```
_layout.jade
index.jade
+ group1
    article1
+ group2
  _data.json
  article1
  article2
```

_layout.jade

```
head
  title= title
  meta(name='description', content='#{ description }')
body
  #wrap
    #side
      p(align='center')
      img(src=sideimg, width='259', height='387', alt=imgtag)
      != partial("_toc.jade")
    #main
      != yield
    #footer
```

_data.json

```
 {
 "article1": {
   "pagetitle": "Article 1 Title",
   "sideimg"  : "/img/freebird.png",
   "imgtag"   : "bird flying under Sun"
 },
 "article2": {
   "pagetitle": "Article 2 Title",
   "sideimg"  : "/img/freebird.png",
   "imgtag"   : "bird flying under Sun"
 }
 }
```

_toc.jade pseudo code (What is proper jade syntax?)

```
if current page is in group1 folder then 
  do nothing
if current page is in group2 folder then
  for each article in group2 folder
    ul
      li
         insert #{ pagetitle } as link in side container
```

I have two questions.

1. If this can be done using a jade partial then what is the syntax for jade code in _toc.jade?
2. If this can be done using block and extend in jade then what is the code in that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The harp documentation contains recipes with clues that I used to solve my own problem using the _toc.jade approach.

_toc.jade (This code works in the context of the original question)

```
if current.path[0] == 'group2'
  for group2, pagetitle in public.group2._data
    a(href="/group2/#{ pagetitle }") 
      p.i= group2.pagetitle
```